# How to find where a given function is called from in gtags

Tags: c, navigation, gtags, source

I am using gtags and can jump to where a function is defined. Howeve I am not able to find inside a function where it is begin called from. Is there anyway to find where a function is called from?

Answer (score 2):

That would be `ggtags-find-reference`, bound by default to `M-]`.

Also, using the "standard" `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` (`M-.`) on a function's prototype should show you its call sites.